# Why websafe string are used to access Data in google endpoints framework?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I did udacity course ud859 on google endpoints framework (Java). For accessing data in cloud datastore I used Objectify. Entity classes were defined in the following way

```
@Entity
public class Profile{
@Id
Long id;
}
```

This "id" attribute is used to identify each profile uniquely and is assigned in a random fashion using ObjectifyFactory instance.

So to access profile data one can form an endpoint "/profile/{id}"

Also this id can be used to make a key using `Key.create(Profile.class,id);` This method returns an instance of type `Key<Profile>`. One of its method `key.getString()` returns a websafestring representing that profile object.

The convention that is taught is to use websafestring for accessing and sharing data of Object over web.

I want to understand how is websafestring safe over web and what are the demerits of using the normally used URL type "/profile/{id}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The websafe string encodes the entire ancestry of a `Key` which is required to look up an entity. A simple use case may define an ID as `Key(MyKind, 1234L)`.  Now if your entity has a parent of `MyParentKind` defined, then it's full key might be more like `Key(MyKind, 1234L, MyParentKind, 5678L)`. A lookup in the ancestry case requires both the ID of the entity as well as the kind + id pairs for all ancestry. The websafe key encodes all of this information into a single string.

ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entity-keys#Java_Ancestor_paths

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation and a good reference to read.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine security is in mind here, but there's really not much difference, as the websafe key string in this case is base64-encoded but not obfuscated, making it easy to obtain the numeric id. If you wanted to hide the database id from the user, you would additionally need to encrypt the key.